# How to send data using get without display parameters in url?

Tags: javascript, laravel, routes, vue.js, laravel-5.3

My case like this :

My view blade laravel like this :

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'shop.payment']) !!}
    <input type="hidden" name="result_type">
    <input type="hidden" name="result_data"">
    ...
    <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="transfer">
    ....
    <checkout-view></checkout-view>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

In view blade laravel exist vue component of checkout view

The component like this :

```
<script>
    export default{
        template:'<button @click="checkout" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" type="submit">Checkout</button>',
        methods: {
            checkout(e){
                if(window.Laravel.hasOwnProperty('auth')) {
                    $('#payment-form').attr('action', '/shop/payment/checkout')
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    $('#payment-form').attr('action', '/shop/detail')
                    $("#payment-form").attr('method', 'get')
                    return true
                }
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

My routes laravel like this :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'shop','as'=>'shop.'], function () {
    Route::get('detail', function(){
        return view('shop.detail');
    });
});
```

If no auth it will run `else` and the url like this :

http://myshop.dev/shop/detail?_token=FLFJ7MfWi1DZv88Uzk2lrBgVXLN6Y3WHTpskDIED&result_type=&result_data=&payment_method=transfer

I want remove the parameter, so the url like this :

http://myshop.dev/shop/detail

I try change to `post`

I change to be like this :

```
$('#payment-form').attr('action', '/shop/detail')
$("#payment-form").attr('method', 'post')
return true
```

And

```
Route::post('detail', function(){
    return view('shop.detail');
});
```

But it does not work, there exist error :

> POST http://myshop.dev/shop/detail 405 (Method Not Allowed)

What is the right solution to solve my problem?

Comment: So for both cases you used post method but this comes out, isn't it?

Comment: @Ataur Rahman Munna, What do you mean? If I use `post`, there exist error

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with `Input` and `get` method:

**View**

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'shop.payment','method' => 'GET']) !!}
    <input type="hidden" name="result_type">
    <input type="hidden" name="result_data"">
    ...
    <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="transfer">
    ....
    <checkout-view></checkout-view>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/test/route', 'TestController@yourFunction');
```

**Controller**

```
public function yourFunction(){

    $result_type = Input::get('result_type');
    $result_data = Input::get('result_date');
    ......

}
```

I hope you understand.

Comment: I want the form to keep using `post`. If the user is guest (no login) it will call `/shop/detail` without parameters in url

Comment: @SuccessMan With Post, what's the problem then ?

Comment: You try to read my question. I have explained it in detail. So I want to change the action if the user is not logged in

Comment: @SuccessMan I've read whole question and upvoted this as good question. I'm not familiar with vue.js. okay

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I just have not found the right answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'shop','as'=>'shop.'], function () {
    Route::get('detail', function(){
    return view('shop.detail');
    });
});
```

I believe the route comes out as **shopdetail**, not **shop/detail**

Type the command `php artisan route:list` to see how laravel sees the urls.

Answer (score 0):

Use return redirect to another route instead of returning a view if there is no auth. In another route on which you are redirecting return the original view which you want to display when there is no authenticated user.